# Output php URL as a bootstrap button only

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

First and foremost excuse me, I'm totally new to PHP.

I'm looking to echo a link back to the comic's description/home page currently being read on my site as a *clickable bootstrap button with a font awesome icon assigned to it*. But, I'm not entirely sure how would I go about doing that.

I'm using a [comic reader](https://foolcode.github.io/FoOlSlide/) software; here's the php code that outputs the link to the comic's home page

```
<?php echo $comic->url() ?>
```

This is the code I've used to output the link inside a bootstrap button with a font awesome icon:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-level-up"><?php echo $comic->url()?></i></button>
```

What happens here is that the url is outputted as a clickable text link using the comic's title inside the button. I'm trying to learn how to have the link phrased as a button only.

Live example: [of the button](http://www.friendshipscans.com/reader/read/test/en/0/0/page/27)

Thanks a lot,

Comment: What is in `var_dump($comic->url())` ? Only URL link, or `<a href="...`

Comment: you can try `echo strip_tags($comic->url())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Comic](https://github.com/FoolCode/FoOlSlide/blob/master/application/models/comic.php) model so you know what `$comic` is set to.
You're using `$comic->url()` which runs:

```
public function url()
{
    return '<a href="' . $this->href() . '" title="' . $this->title() . '">' . $this->title() . '</a>';
}
```

But if you only want the href part, the above function calls this method:

```
public function href()
{
    return site_url('series/' . $this->stub);
}
```

So your solution is as simple as:

```
<?= $comic->href() ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate! While everyone elses' solution worked too, yours helped me get what I was after. Just a button linking back to the comic's home page, with no text in it.

And thanks for putting out to the the comic model. Helped get a better understand of how the links are phrased.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your site , i saw that , coming `<?php echo $comic->url()?>` is doing echo of link with anchor tag as well , then i did visit the comic reader's repository on github , and explored the code files and i found that there are two type of linking system :

1. $comic->url(); - this echo the link with anchor tag
2. $comic->href(); - this echo only the link that you need , in your case

and for title echo you can use the below

```
<?php echo $comic->title();?>
```

You can create an anchor tag and give that anchor tag the classes that you have given to the button and use `$comic->href();` to get only the link that you need.

```
<a href="<?php echo $comic->href();?>" class="btn btn-danger">
   <i class="fa fa-level-up"></i><?php echo $comic->title();?>
</a>
```

as **Rohit kishore** suggested , you can also try to use `echo strip_tags($comic->url())` if you have to use `$comic->url();`

```
<a href="<?php echo strip_tags($comic->url());?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-level-up"><?php echo $comic->title();?></i></a>
```